# Converting ASCII text to Unicode with formatting

Tags: linux, unicode, ascii

Is there a free tool under linux system, for converting ascii text to unicode by keeping original text formatting ?

Comment: "Unicode" is not an encoding.

Comment: ASCII text is already in Unicode. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Describe what your understanding of "ascii text" and "unicode" is. In fact, any "ascii text" is already (UTF-8 encoded) Unicode, since ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.

Comment: since ArmASCII is subset of UTF-8/16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iconv](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/documentation/libiconv/iconv.1.html) can convert between different encodings, if that's what you mean.

Comment: One more possibility is to use Far Manager's built-in text editor: select all text, cut (Ctrl+X), change encoding (Shift-F8) to UTF-8, paste (Ctrl+V). Save file. (I run Far under VirtualBox, but you can use Wine as well)

Comment: @18446744073709551615 You could make that your own answer instead of a comment, but it's not a very good one, since the question asks for a Linux tool.

Comment: no I cannot: it's closed. And I _am_ under Linux.

Comment: Any tool that requires Wine or VirtualBox can hardly be considered a Linux tool.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, it's called `cat`:

```
cat myasciifile > myunicodefile
```

Now `myunicodefile` consists of unicode codepoints, encoded in the popular UTF8 encoding. Note that this assumes that `myasciifile` consists only of legal ASCII characters (i.e. in the range 0-127).

An alternative to this is `cp`.